# How to wrap Express route in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, express

I want to make a `loginRequired` wrapper for my Express route, but I'm having troubles finding the correct types.

Here's my `loginRequired` wrapper:

```js
export const loginRequired = (fn) => (req, res, next) => {
    // If unauthorized
    if(!req.session.currentUser) {
        return res.status(401).send({
            status: 'error'
            message: 'Login required'
        })
    };

    // else if authorized execute normally
    return fn(req, res, next)
}
```

Now to wrap my route handler:

```js
app.get('/protected', loginRequired(req, res, next) => {
    return res.next({secret: 'foo'});
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction, RequestHandler } from 'express-serve-static-core';

export const loginRequired = (
    fn: RequestHandler
) => (
    req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction
): ReturnType<RequestHandler> => {
    if (!req.session.currentUser) {
        return res.status(401).send({
            status: 'error',
            message: 'Login required'
        });
    }
    return fn(req, res, next);
};
```